# Bridge ngon to quads

Tags: retopology

I want to easily cut an ngon along existing vertices into quads. For testing purposes I cut a cylinder out of a cube, which generates an ngon on top.

[image: cube after boolean operation]

At the moment I do all cuts manually with the knife tool (see 2nd picture, I only cut the right half for demonstration).

[image]

Can I automate this process somehow or like "extrude" the vertices from the arc to the top edge to create these quads?

(and is my idea of this quaded edge topology good :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hello yes there a little hack for doing this, but in this weird way...

---

select some vertices and extrude them to the axis to point the edge loops, then flatten with <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and again <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Y or X</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, and then enable automerge and split edges option, and enable snapping with edge center, and then move the vertices and snap them and click for applying, and then repeat the same in the other edges...
then set snapping to vertices, and manually snap and apply each vertex in the last intersections...
and then add some loopcuts with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and manually select 2 edge loops vertices and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to connect them, and repeat the same for the remaining things to clean up...
[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's what I'm looking for. Thumbs up.